# При клике записать значение в input

Tags: javascript

Есть class="quantity" в этот класс должны приходить значения количество детей у которых выбран возраст. В class="number_val" возраст ребенка, а в class="input_val" value без текста только число

```js
$('.quantity').click(function () {
  $('.children_box').toggleClass('open');
});
$('.children_input').click(function () {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open');
});
$('.children_box .option').click(function() {
  var num = $(this).text();
  $(this).closest('.children_box').find('.input_val').val(num);
  $(this).closest('.children_box').find('.number_val').html(num);
  $('.children_age').removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
.select {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.quantity {
    height: 45px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
.children_box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f2efef;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
.children_box.open {
  display: block;
}
.children_input {
  background-color: #d8d5e2;
  padding: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.children_age {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #d8d5e2;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.children_age.open {
  display: block;
}
.children_age li:hover {
  background-color: #f4f2f9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <div class="quantity">
    <span class="quantity_val">&mdash;</span>
    <input class="input_quantity" type="hidden"  value="">
  </div>
  <div class="children_box">
    <div class="children-item">
      <label class="children-title">
        Возраст 1 ребенка
      </label>
      <div class="children_input">
        <span class="number_val">&mdash;</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
      </div>
      <ul class="children_age">
        <li class="option">Меньше года</li>
        <li class="option">1 год</li>
        <li class="option">2 года</li>
        <li class="option">3 года</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="children-item">
      <label class="children-title">
        Возраст 2 ебенка
      </label>
      <div class="children_input">
        <span class="number_val">&mdash;</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
      </div>
      <ul class="children_age">
        <li class="option">Меньше года</li>
        <li class="option">1 год</li>
        <li class="option">2 года</li>
        <li class="option">3 года</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

[Вот ссылка на код](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/665250/)

Comment: Почему бы не использовать `<select>` в вашем случае?

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с комментарием по поводу `select`. но если уж надо кастомизировать, что невозможно с помощью `select`. то лучше разделить обработчики, Йа считаю)

```js
var main = [];
function addToMain(text, index) {
 main[index] = text;
  $('.main').attr('value', main);
}

$('.second').on('click', 'li', function(){
 var text = $(this).text();
  var index = 1;
 $(this).addClass('check');
  $(this).parent().prev().attr('value', text.slice(0, 1));
  addToMain(text, index);
});
$('.first').on('click', 'li', function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  var index = 0;
 $(this).addClass('check');
  $(this).parent().prev().attr('value', text);
  addToMain(text, index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
<input type="text" class="main">
<br>
<br>
  <div class="first">
    <input type="text" class="children first_input">
    <ul>
      <li>1 one</li>
      <li>2 two</li>
      <li>3 three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <input type="text" class="children second_input">
    <ul>
      <li>1 one</li>
      <li>2 two</li>
      <li>3 three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```